# Combine bar plot and stat_smooth() line from different data sets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to overlay a `stat_smooth()` line from one dataset over a bar plot of another. Both csv files draw from the same dataset, but I had to make a new one for the bar plot because I had to add a few columns (including error bars) that wouldn't make sense in the big csv. So, I have code for the bar plot, and code for the line made using stat_smooth, but can't figure out how to combine them. I just want a graph with the line on top of the bars. Here's the code for the bar plot:

```
`e <- read.csv("Retro Complex.csv", header=T, sep=",")
 e <- subset(e, Accuracy != 0)
limits <- aes(ymax = Confidence + SE, ymin = Confidence - SE)
e$Complexity <- factor(e$Complexity)
p <- ggplot(e, aes(e$Complexity, Confidence))
p +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = "dodge", width = 0.25) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  ggtitle("Retro")`
```

And here's for the line

```
`ggplot(retroacc, aes(x=Complexity.Sample, y=risk)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(x=Complexity.Sample, y=risk), data=retroacc,
    method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=FALSE) +
  ylim(0,1)`
```

Here's what they both look like:

`Stat_smooth()` line:

[image]

Barplot:

[image]

Sample Data
For the bar plot:

```
structure(list(Complexity = structure(1:5, .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), Accuracy = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), Risk = c(0.69297164, 0.695793434, 0.695891571, 0.746606335, 
0.748717949), SE = c(0.003621776, 0.004254081, 0.00669456, 0.008114764, 
0.021963804), Proportion = c(0.823475656, 0.809299751, 0.863727821, 
0.94724695, 0.882352941), SEAcc = c(0.002716612, 0.003267882, 
0.004639995, 0.004059001, 0.015325003)), .Names = c("Complexity", 
"Accuracy", "Confidence", "SE", "Proportion", "SEAcc"), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

For the line:

```
structure(list(risk = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), acc = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Uniqueness = c(0.405166959, 0.407414244, 0.285123931, 0.248994487, 
    0.259019778, 0.334552913, 0.300580793, 0.354632526, 0.309841996, 
    0.331460876, 0.289981111, 0.362405881, 0.37389863, 0.253672193, 
    0.342903451, 0.294459829, 0.387447291, 0.519657612, 0.278964406
    ), Average.Similarity = c(0.406700667, 0.409547355, 0.275663862, 
    0.240909144, 0.251796956, 0.31827466, 0.240574971, 0.349093002, 
    0.34253811, 0.348084627, 0.290495997, 0.318312198, 0.404143605, 
    0.290789337, 0.293259599, 0.320214236, 0.382449298, 0.506295194, 
    0.335167223), Complexity.Sample = c(8521L, 11407L, 3963L, 
    2536L, 2327L, 3724L, 4005L, 5845L, 5770L, 5246L, 3629L, 3994L, 
    4285L, 1503L, 8222L, 3683L, 5639L, 10288L, 3076L)), .Names = c("risk", 
"acc", "Uniqueness", "Average.Similarity", "Complexity.Sample"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

So yeah, if any of you guys know how to combine these into one plot please let me know!!

Comment: can you not get what you want from `p + stat_smooth(aes(x=Complexity.Sample, y=risk), data=retroacc,
    method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=FALSE)` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is very helpful if you provide some example data when asking a question.  That way people have a minimum working example to start from.

Comment: @IanWesley, I'm having trouble figuring out how to provide data without just copying it and pasting it from excel..I've seen examples from other questions but can't find how they did it. How can I do that?

Comment: @Pdubbs, I've tried but it spits back "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Confidence' not found". I've tried in several different forms, and nada

Comment: @GB1 the `dput(YOUR_OBJECT)` command will output a command to create your data in R.  it sounds like `e` is pretty big, so you might want to just output a subset for us. (make sure your subset generates the same error)

Comment: @Pdubbs, would it be possible for me to just copy and paste a subset from the dataset as seen when entering View()?

Comment: @IanWesley just made a smaller csv to add sample data, so here's some!

Comment: @Pdubbs just made a smaller csv to add sample data! Thanks so much for your guys' help.

Comment: If you want to overlay the two plots, why do you have different x axis for the barplot and smooth ? One uses "Complexity" and the other "compelxity.sampe". Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @LoBu "Complexity" is a binned version of "Complexity.Sample", but I would want "Complexity"'s x axis to be the X-axis on the combined plot. Essentially I just want to put the line from stat_smooth and put it right on top of the bar plot, maintaining the bar plot's axes. I should have clarified

Comment: You have different X axis’s, one of the charts will have to be manipulated, and then you are messing up the visualization aspect